# In a spoiler, a link shows and hides more quickly compared to normal text

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, spoilers

Hover over the following spoiler.

> 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)) 45 48 51 54 57 60 63 66 69 72 75 78 81 84 87 90

The number 42 is darker than other numbers because it is a link.  (The number 42 is not special; it is the same if you use something else as link text.)  Like this: (screenshot when the spoiler is being shown)

[image]

and this: (screenshot when the spoiler is being hidden)

[image]

(These screenshots are extremely difficult to capture without recording a video.)  It feels that the link only takes about half the time to show and hide.  The red circles are drawn by hand rather than generated.

I am using Firefox Quantum 68.0.1 (64-bit) with no active extensions, plugins, or user scripts.  I was logged in if that's relevant.

---

> This spoiler exist solely to [prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_(truth)) that the number "forty-two" is not the problem.

Comment: I tagged this discussion instead of bug because I am not confident in my sense of color.  I need you to confirm this for me :)

Comment: It's a CSS color transition to/from a fixed value but they're starting/ending at different colors so they will not have the same intermediate values.

Comment: Reproducible on Android chrome.

Comment: It seems that this issue has been fixed by the recent (?) revamp of spoilers.